# How can I extract the text portion of a binary file in Linux/Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a binary file. If I open it with [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), it shows sequences of human-readable text and binary characters. What is the best way to extract the human-readable portion only using Bash?

I was thinking, maybe we can do this over a [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) pattern?

```
cat file1.bin | grep '????'  > newfile.txt
```

Comment: `strings file1.bin`

Comment: @MarcB  please make that an answer so we can vote properly...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `strings` utility - that's exactly what it's designed for.

Comment: I tried that before it didn't work. But then I realized i missed the s. strings not string , my bad :-) Thank you!

Comment: so how to use strings?

Comment: @Zimba `man strings`

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I used in a system that didn't have the "strings" utility installed

```
cat yourfilename | tr -cd "[:print:]"
```

This prints the text and removes unprintable characters in one fell swoop, unlike "cat -v filename" which prints only text but requires some postprocessing to remove unwanted stuff. Note that some of the binary data may be printable so you'll still get some gibberish between the good stuff. I think strings removes this gibberish too if you can use that.

Comment: `strings ~/Pictures/Pic_A.jpg` has result (or better). `$ cat ~/Pictures/Pic_A.jpg | tr -cd "[:print:]"`     Result: `tr: Illegal byte sequence`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Debian distro, you can probably get [radare2](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2) (r2) with just `sudo apt install radare2`.

After you've installed r2, either with `apt`, some other installer on some other distro, or by following an online guide, you can use `rabin2` to extract just the text part of a binary:

`$ rabin2 -z your_binary`

This is often "better" than just `strings` because it outputs just the useful `.data` section of the binary. Stuff outside that section isn't always very useful.

Comment: This solution only works for executable files, as the tool is reverse engineering focused. Not every binary file is executable (thus, not having a .data section).

Comment: Interesting strings like passwords and paths hard-coded into binaries, as far as I know, are usually in the `.data` section so using `rabin2 -z` goes straight to those without printing the gibberish we get when using `strings`. I do use both though.

Comment: My comment was made to make it clear to readers the use case in which your tool works. Your use case is specific to executables, as you keep mentioning the `.data` section. The use case that landed me on this question was a nonexecutable binary file having no `.data` section for `rabin2` to operate on. `strings` is useful on more than just executables. :-)